# Webpack, html-loader, file-loader and extract-loader

Tags: webpack

I'm starting my learning path with webpack and I've hit a problem, which I think is caused by `extract-loader`. When webpack grabs my HTML file, it seems to be unable to properly compile, giving an error on the use of `import.meta`. I think the error, rather than being a true error, indicates a problem with my understanding of how webpack and its loaders work. Can someone give a look at my files and see if they spot a mistake?

I'm using node v15.12.0, and npm v7.6.3.

Thank you very much.

**package.json**

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "extract-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.28.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**:

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].html'
            }
          },
          'extract-loader',
          'html-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**src/main.js**

```js
require('./style.css')
require('./index.html')
```

**src/style.css**:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

**src/index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Webpack output:

```
$ npx webpack
asset bundle.js 19.6 KiB [compared for emit] (name: main)
runtime modules 937 bytes 4 modules
cacheable modules 8.95 KiB
  modules by path ./src/ 737 bytes
    modules by path ./src/*.css 651 bytes
      ./src/style.css 326 bytes [built] [code generated]
      ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/style.css 325 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./src/main.js 47 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./src/index.html 39 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]
  modules by path ./node_modules/ 8.23 KiB
    ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js 6.67 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js 1.57 KiB [built] [code generated]

ERROR in ./src/index.html
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/extract-loader/lib/extractLoader.js):
SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (3:54)
  1 | // Imports
  2 | import ___HTML_LOADER_GET_SOURCE_FROM_IMPORT___ from "../node_modules/html-loader/dist/runtime/getUrl.js";
> 3 | var ___HTML_LOADER_IMPORT_0___ = new URL("./main.js", import.meta.url);
    |                                                       ^
  4 | // Module
  5 | var ___HTML_LOADER_REPLACEMENT_0___ = ___HTML_LOADER_GET_SOURCE_FROM_IMPORT___(___HTML_LOADER_IMPORT_0___);
  6 | var code = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<body>\n    <h1>Hello world!</h1>\n    <script src=\"" + ___HTML_LOADER_REPLACEMENT_0___ + "\"></script>\n</body>\n</html>\n\n";
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (/home/jdferreira/Repositories/Temps/extract-loader-issue/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4454:13)
```

Comment: Not sure what are you doing by importing `html` file in the main file (I suppose this is your entry point)?

Comment: I get what you're saying. I've updated the question to use the HTML as the entry point and to remove its import from the JS file. However, the problem persists.

Comment: I've also tried to turn off the esModule of html-loader, but then the error gets wonkier: it seems the CSS code is inserted verbatim in a JS file, since the error I get is starts with `(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { body {`

Comment: Nope. If you wish to set `index.html` as your index file, you should use html plugin instead of importing. BTW, please don't never set html file as entry point your app in webpack config file

Comment: My idea is to process the HTML file and save it as a standalone file, particularly because I may want the CSS file to be standalone later on the development instead of inlining it with JS. That's why I'm importing the HTML in the main.js. Perhaps there's another way? I'm following a rather old (webpack 4) tutorial at youtube (https://youtu.be/PwJVivB_XcE?t=334) which does it like that, but in the video's case it works, while with the current versions of these tools it does not.

Comment: Did you ever sort this out @jdferreira?

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in `extract-loader` when used with Webpack 5:
https://github.com/peerigon/extract-loader/issues/111

I'm having the same problem and aparently there is no solution until now. If you can, try to use webpack 4.

Or you can look at [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#usage), maybe it is userful for your case.

Comment: It does not seem to be an issue with `"css-loader": "^3.4.2"`.